# PHP JSON data build and form submission redirect on one page

Tags: php, javascript, json, redirect, form-submit

I am trying to build some graphs using PHP and Google Charts. I have a PHP page that contains a form where the user chooses the information that they want to see displayed on a graph. The form contains data such as date range, total sales, net, etc. The form submits to GraphData.php. Here I want to generate the MySql query based on data received from the form submission. I use that data to build a JSON object for the Google Charts. Then submit a form containing the userid and session variables to the Graphs.php page. Here we use Ajax to grab the JSON data and create the Google Chart. I am having trouble with the redirect/form submission to Graphs.php. Is this possible? Here is my code for GraphData.php:

```
// mysql stuff here ....
$result = mysql_query($sql, $myconn) or die(mysql_error());

//start the json data in the format Google Chart js/API expects to recieve it
$data = array('cols' => array(array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
                          array('label' => 'Ticket Sales', 'type' => 'number'),
                          array('label' => 'Amount Bet', 'type' => 'number'),
                          array('label' => 'Amount Won', 'type' => 'number'),
                          array('label' => 'Total Net', 'type' => 'number')),
          'rows' => array());

// loop through the results and add them to the json object
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row[0]), array('v' => $row[1]), array('v' => $row[2]), array('v' => $row[3]), array('v' => $row[4])));
}

echo json_encode($data);
echo("<FORM id='redirect' name='redirect' method='POST' action='Graphs.php'>
        <INPUT type='hidden' name='userid' value='$userid'>
        <INPUT type='hidden' name='session' value='$session'>'
      </form>");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit () {
var frm = document.getElementById("redirect");
frm.submit();
}
window.onload = submit;
</script>
```

The page successfully redirects to Graphs.php, but the form is not being submitted and I get an error saying that the JSON string is invalid. Is what I am trying to do indeed possible? Am I just doing it wrong? Or is there another way? Sorry if this is confusing. Let me know if you would like more information. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Really?? Not one answer? Maybe I can put this in a more general scope. Is it possible to submit to a page, have it handle data, and then submit itself to another page?

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate the page jumping entirely by using hidden values in each form to determine the page action using either if/then's or a switch statement if you have multiple possible values. As pseudo:

```
if ($_POST[myHiddenInput]==null){
        (means the form hasn't been submitted)
        load or echo options form (form submits to this page)
}
else{
        (they submitted the filled out form)
        check the form for errors, re-populate and prompt if needed, etc.
        if no errors, query mysql (use PDO or face problems later),
         generate json from your sql response and use file_get_contents()
         or curl() google to get your chart, echo response to screen

}
```

You can, carefully, nest php inside javascript, allowing you to have a php function that creates your json and returns it to a javascript function call (ie: a jquery ajax request) just keep in mind that only happens at page load.